# Problem with piping emails to script

Tags: php, email, cpanel, piping

I have a script to capture emails that are piped to it, parse the parts and insert them into a database.  The script works fine and I've tested it over and over forwarding my own email to it.  However, when I forward the client's email to the same script, the emails bounce with the following error:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/etc/ixed/ixed.4.4.lin' - /etc/ixed/ixed.4.4.lin: undefined symbol: empty_string in Unknown on line 0

I've done the following to try and correct other problems that were causing bounces, but this one seems to be at a lower level:

- added "-q" to the pipe command, such as "|/usr/bin/php -q /home/path/to/script"
- added error_reporting(0) to top of script
- Ensured there are no blank spaces outside of the <%%> tags to cause output.

If anyone has seen this before and found a solution, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `error_reporting` setting is to late (the error is a start up one, before error_reporting is called). Options (in personally prefered order):

- Fix the incorrect PHP setting somewhere (run `php --ini` to check which files are loaded and remove the line(s) referencing ixid or fix the library itself)
- Run with complete default settings (so no php.ini is loaded: `| /usr/bin/php -n /home/path/to/script`
- Run with displaying of errors suppressed: `| /usr/bin/php -d display_errors=0 /home/path/to/script`

It might not a bad idea to run with `display_errors` off by default of course, and only log errors, as your users should never have to deal with errors & error-descriptions they can't fix themselves.